# NSInputStream and NSOutputStream problems

Tags: ios, nsstream, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream

I have two `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` between devices that are connected to each other via network. When I write something in `output stream`, the data is written until the  `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event occurs. I close the output stream but on the other side (`input stream`) the `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event never occurs, until I exit the view controller of the `output stream`. So:
 1. Why does not the `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event occurs at `input stream` even after the the same occurred at the `output stream` ? (the output stream is even closed in this event)
 2. It is my understanding that, once you open the `NSOutputStream`, you can only write data once. Opening the `output stream` again after `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event (for example to write something new on any event) is not possible, right ????

Answer (score 3):

I probably need more info about your connection and how you're sending your data but let me try and answer your questions:

1.

You're not encountering an end of your `inputstream` because you never started reading from it. The `outputstream` finished writing because it probably encountered an end, just like you said.

Imagine Jacob (your `outputstream`) delivering a envelope (your data) to his friend's house. Jacob puts the envelope on his friend's doormat and walks back to his own house. **At this point Jacob's work is done** so he tells himself that he's done (in your case the `outputstream` signals an `NSStreamEventEndEncountered`).

Jacob's friend George (your `inputstream`) could see the envelope or not, but nevertheless never looks what is in it. **So unless George takes the envelope and looks what is inside it**, he could never tell himself that he finished looking at it (in your case the `inputstream` never signals an `NSStreamEventEndEncountered`).

2.

This actually depends on how you plan to use your `outputstream`. If you plan to send data multiple times to the same device, why not leave the `outputstream` open? You can write data as long as the socket is open and there is space available. When you close the `outputstream` you need to reopen it however.